# How do I use the login in Facebook SDK 4.6 for iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, swift2

I was using this code to FB login:

```
@IBAction func fbloginbtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email","user_location","user_about_me", "user_photos", "user_website"], handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil){
                            //do sth
                        }
                    })
                }
            } 
        }
    })
}
```

But `loginwithreadpermissions` is deprecated in SDK 4.6

How should I change this code?

Comment: Just to make sure, 4.6 is the **Facebook** SDK version, right? Not the **iOS** SDK version? (that would be too old).

Comment: oh sorry yes it is Facebook SDK for iOS

Comment: Perhaps it is obvious for someone familiar with the Facebook SDK, but for everyone else it might be slightly confusing. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: If you didn't already know - if all you want is social sharing, you don't have to use the Facebook SDK if the user has the Facebook app installed. See this Twitter example http://www.raywenderlich.com/21558/beginning-twitter-tutorial-updated-for-ios-6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, you'll see the mention of alternative api as well.
From the documentation of [`FBSDKLoginManager`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/), it says:

```
- (void)logInWithReadPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
                         handler:(FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)handler
__attribute__((deprecated("use logInWithReadPermissions: fromViewController:handler: instead")));
```

So there is a new method, that takes an additional parameter of `UIViewController` as well, to determine from where the login sequence was initiated. As documentation says:

```
- (void)logInWithReadPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
              fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController
              handler:(FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)handler;
```

and the explanation for parameters says:

> **`fromViewController`** - The view controller to present from. If nil, the
>   topmost view controller will be automatically determined as best as
>   possible.

Since, there's only one additional parameter, you could add it to existing implementation like this:

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "others"],
                           fromViewController:self //<=== new addition, self is the view controller where you're calling this method.
                           handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
})
```

The latest xcode should also suggest you when you write, `logInWithReadPermissions` with all available options.

Comment: An example in swift would be perfect for me as a beginner to understand.

Comment: @AdilSoomro I used to check if my token was valid to determine if the user needed to login again. Do you have something on that? This here used to be my code: "if([FBSession activeSession].state == FBSessionStateOpen)".

Comment: @FelipeGringo you can get the current access token using [`FBSDKAccessToken`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAccessToken/) class and their's a static method that will give you current access token if any. `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` You can check if a user has granted particular permission, get all granted permissions, declined permissions, expiry date etc.